# C# Keyboard Hook - Keys Disabled

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

I am not particularly familiar with Keyboard hooks and might have completely the wrong understanding of how to use the but I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out.

Using some online tutorials and sample code i have implemented a keyboard hook. The way in which i need my program to work is to sit idle in the background and to wait for a specific key to be pressed in order to "wake up" the program. My issue is that although my keyboard hook below works, it picks up every key and stops them working with any other program whilst the hook is active. Is there a way for the hook to pass all keys except the one i want to "wake up" my program? or is there a better/different way for me to achieve this?

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

     private static IntPtr HookCallback(
   int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            if (vkCode.ToString() == "162")
            {
                UnHook();
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.ShowDialog();
                _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    public static void UnHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        UnHook();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Ben

Comment: When you add code, please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30674879/edit) link at the bottom of your question and make sure to user code-formatting so it is easy to read. Also take a look at how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get it down to just the essential code necessary to demonstrate what's needed.

Comment: My apologies but i seem to have fixed my problem and the code i have attached to this question actually works as i want it to. I believe that my issue was to do with the way in which i was previously calling`                    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);`

Comment: Please click on the blue button "Answer your question"